# Is it normal for manufacturers to use different memory chips for the same model?

Tags: memory

I ordered four sticks of Hynix HMA82GU6MFR8N-TF (16GB DDR4 2133Mhz w/ECC) which all arrived with matching part number stickers. But one of the sticks is layed out differently and uses slightly different chips.

Three of the sticks use chips labeled H5AN8G8NAFR:

https://www.skhynix.com/products.view.do?vseq=2100&cseq=73

And one stick uses chips labeled H5AN8G8NMFR:

https://www.skhynix.com/products.view.do?vseq=1965&cseq=73

The chips are all identified by Hynix as such:

```
H5AN8G8NAFR  8Gb  x8  1.2V  PB/RD/TF/UH/VK  Normal Power  FBGA  Mass production
H5AN8G8NMFR  8Gb  x8  1.2V  TF/UH/VK        Normal Power  FBGA  Mass production
```

All sticks are labeled as `TF` which matches the "speed" rating by Hynix, despite being different chips.

These are all matching sticks according to the part number but I find it interesting that the layout and chips used on one of the sticks is different. Is it normal for manufacturers to use different memory chips for the same model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably they just ran out of old components and had to rearrange the design a little, still maintaining the same part number. Hypothetically the backwards compatibility may have reduced a little since the `H5AN8G8NMFR` doesn't support 1600/1866 MHz anymore, but let's face that no-one really buys these to be used on a same system with some older memory. They both do what has been promised in the label (16GB DDR4 2133Mhz w/ECC) and can share the same part number.

See if they have a different revision number. An ideal reseller wouldn't mix different revisions when selling ECC memory for servers, but it's not exceptional due to the same EAN code.

Comment: The numbers are identical everywhere on the label between the two kinds of sticks. The only reason I even noticed that the sticks were different was that the PCB had a different layout.

Comment: Then it seems there's nothing wrong: if you face any problems using the same part number products together, it should be covered by the warranty. Fortunately there's no elf inside the server who could think this as an aesthetic decoration problem. :)

Comment: What about the elf outside the server who KNOWS? D: